# Invertibility of the matrix $(I-\lambda W)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it necessary that $\lambda \in (0,1)$ for $(I-\lambda W)$ to be invertible, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $W$ is a zero diagonal matrix with row sums are all 1, and each element of $W$ is in $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 0):

No. The map $\lambda\mapsto\det(\operatorname{Id}-\lambda W)$ is a polynomial map which is not the null map (take $\lambda=0$). So, it can only have finitely many zeros. Therefore, there have to be $\lambda$'s outside $(0,1)$ for which $\operatorname{Id}-\lambda W$ is invertible too.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $I - \lambda W$ is not invertible if and only if $\lambda \in \sigma(W)$. Since the spectrum of a matrix $\sigma(W)$ is a finite set, its complement certainly intersects $\mathbb{R} \setminus (0,1)$, so there are $\lambda \in (0,1)$ such that $I - \lambda W$ is invertible.